# Fix possible null warning

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I get a resharper warning

[image]

The NotNull used to work, I wonder if it the nullable reference type compiler support (We havent enabled nullable support in this project, but the `GetManifestResourceStream` methods returns a nullable reference type

```
public virtual Stream? GetManifestResourceStream(string name) { throw NotImplemented.ByDesign; }
```

My code

```
public static T NotNull<T>(this T source) where T : class
{
    if (source == null) throw new NullReferenceException($"{typeof(T).FullName}: Expected reference type that is not null");

    return source;
}
```

edit: This seems to work

```
#nullable enable
public static T NotNull<T>(this T? source) where T : class
{
    if (source == null) throw new NullReferenceException($"{typeof(T).FullName}: Expected reference type that is not null");

    return source;
}
```

Comment: Why do you throw `NullReferenceException`? Why don't you use `ArgumentNullException`?

Comment: Doesnt matter really. Its just syntax sugar for the compiler/resharper not to throw warnings.

Comment: The caller except it to be not null btw, so its more a null reference exception than argument exception. Since this is a helper extension method

Comment: You can use `!` to suppress nullable warnings -- that's cleaner, if you're throwing an exception either way

Comment: Cool I have missed that keyword., The NotNull orginally came from we had nullable structs that was not null known by domain because of the state it was in.

Comment: @canton7 write a answer and I mark as answer

Comment: One downside of ! keyword is this var myNotNull = somefoo.NotNull(); myNotNull.CallOne(); myNotNull.CallTwo(); You cant doo var myNotNull = somefoo!;

Comment: [Sure you can](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFAGIB2BXANlghgIywFMACItA45KAZhNhIGESBvZEj+uqAFhIFkAFFDgAGAPwkAzgEpW7TooBuuAE4kALiQC80gIQBuBYo4iAnII0A6ADLkA5hoAWMo0kUBfZB6A=)

Comment: It works but resharper throws warning

Comment: Sounds like a R# problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking to get rid of the nullable warnings, and throw an exception either way, you might as well just use the [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving) `!`:

```
await stream!.CopyToAsync(memory);
```